# javascript callbacks based on html/php output, retrieving variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-plugins, post

I am using jquery to post data from forms (through the jquery form plugin - http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)

The only callback that I am able to receive (in the "success:" portion) is the "html" using success: function(html) { ... }.

Can you only differentiate the success response based on the html output?

Basically I want something that can do this..

success: function(html, some_other_variable) {

if (some_other_variable == 1) {

//do something

} else {

//do something else

}

}

I have been reading here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ .. but no luck

Thanks in advance,
Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, you could actually send json back, with any param you want. Don't know how the syntax is in PHP is, but in .NET MVC you could do like this.

Ajax call

```
$.ajax({ dataType: 'json' ... });
```

Returning result

```
return Json(new {status = "your status", html = "your html"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And in your success callback function

```
  success: function (response) {
    if (response.status == 'success') {
      var html = response.html;
      // do something with html
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: As you gave practically the same answer I did, I'll offer the PHP syntax: `return json_encode( Array( 'status' => 'your status', 'html' => 'your html' ) );`

Comment: As you pratically answered at the same time as I did, I didn't know. But good thing you knew the PHP syntax.

Comment: No no--sorry--I wasn't saying you copied my answer or anything. Sorry for the poor wording! You even beat me by a few seconds. I just meant I wanted to chip in to your answer with the PHP as it is a valid answer. I +1'd your answer too. :)

Comment: thanks for your help. i did want the response in PHP so both of your answers helped immensely.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.. JAAulde - No hard feelings, just some misunderstanding :)

Answer (score 0):

The data you return from the server is the data you get in the success method. You can return a different structure which contains your desired status var and the markup you want:

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "html": "<p>Test</p>"
}
```

And set your `dataType` option to 'json'.

Or you could add an output header and ask for that header form the XHR object.

Answer (score 0):

The `success` function actually responds with 4 parameters, responseText, statusText, xhr object, and a jQuery wrapped form element. [(documentation)](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object)

If you set the `dataType` to 'json' then the response coming back will be parsed JSON.

Let's say the page you're doing the POST to responds with

```
{
   success: true,
   name: 'hello',
   someothervalue: 'world'
}
```

And your code is...

```
$('form').ajaxForm({
    dataType: 'json',
    success(response, status, xhr, form) {
        alert(response.name);
    }
});
```

In that case `response` would be populated with the json and you could access as shown.

The trick here is that you need whatever the page the form is POST'ing to, to actually return a JSON response.

Comment: IMO, the response status is of very limited use in the success method. But I think you agree as you showed how to send his own structure with status therein. :)

Comment: does this mean i would need to encode the php output in json? (using json_encode)